# The order of a group with some properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question originates from an abstract algebra exam in 2013. Here is the description.

Let $G$ be a finite commutative group. Suppose there exists a mapping $f:G\times G\rightarrow \mathbb C^*$ satisfying the following conditions: (where $\mathbb C^*=\mathbb C-\{0\}$ represents the multiplicative group of all non-zero complex numbers)

(1) For any $g,g_1,g_2\in G$, $f(g,g_1g_2)=f(g,g_1)f(g,g_2)$,

(2) For any $g,g_1,g_2\in G$, $f(g_1g_2,g)=f(g_1,g)f(g_2,g)$,

(3) For any $g\in G$, $f(g,g)=1$,

(4) For $g\in G$, if for every $h\in G$, $f(g,h)=1$, then $g=1_G$, where $1_G$ is the identity element of the group G.

Prove that the order $|G|$ of $G$ is a square number.

**My attempts so far:**

(i) For all $g_1,g_2\in G$, $1=f(g_1g_2,g_1g_2)=f(g_1,g_2)f(g_2,g_1)$, so $f(g_2,g_1)=f(g_1,g_2)^{-1}$.

(ii) For all $g\in G$, $f(g,1)=f(g,1)f(g,1)$, so $f(g,1)=1$. Similarly $f(1,g)=1$ for all $g\in G$.

(iii) For all  $g_1,g_2\in G$, $f(g_1,g_2)$ is a root of $x^{|G|}=1$.

**An example when $|G|=6$:**

Let $G=\langle a,b\ |\ a^3=b^2=1\rangle$. It is easy to obtain

$$f(a^2,a^i)=1,\quad i=0,1,2,$$

moreover,

$$f(a^2,b)=f(a,b)^2=f(a,b^2)=f(a,1_G)=1,$$

so $f(a^2,g)=1$ for all $g\in G$, which contradicts the condition (4).

Any comments or answers are appreciated.

Comment: In (4) I think you mean "for every $h \in G$", not "for any $h \in G$". "for any $h \in G$" is linguistically ambiguous in English.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the question.

Comment: Notice that I found the duplicate(s) as the first google search result with the query: "finite abelian group" "pairing" "square". Why it's the same: The pairing here factors over the torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This can quite easily be reduced to the $p$-group case: $f$ is the pointwise product of its restrictions to the $p$-Sylow groups, and all these restrictions again satisfy the conditions (1)-(4).